# When wiil this person be able to replace his engines on a bunch of smaller ones to attach them on clothes?

Tags: engine

That is the real question that bothered me.
 [UK 'Iron Man' suit](http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-39441825)

Comment: Turbojet, yes but why, no you don't need to cooler.

Answer (score 3):

From the outlet cowling and nozzle, it they look to me like 6 standard RC jet engines (JetCat or so; [JETCAT P200RX](http://www.dreamworksrc.com/catalog/Jetcat-P200Rx), for instance, has about 50 lbs of thrust, so in the right order of magnitude).

I don't think there would be any benefit whatsoever to using many miniature engines.

Answer (score 2):

It certainly looks like some form of jet engines, probably turbojets as they are simpler and have better thrust to weight and thrust to size ratios than turbofans (though you pay for it in fuel consumption).

In general small engines perform worse than larger ones, so it pays to keep your engine counts to a minimum.

Comment: If using small engines, fans/propellers could do it. You would have to mount them on a frame though.